How to interrupt Java Future
I am trying to cancel + interrupt a Java CompletableFuture. However, the async thread does not get interrupted, even when using future.cancel(true).
e.g.
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class InterruptedSleepingThreadMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Sleep");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Future Done");
        });
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e) {}
        future.cancel(true);
        System.out.println(future.isCancelled());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}

Sleep
true
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Done

Notice how the while-loop continues executing and the catch block is never executed?
What is the best way to interrupt this future? Must I implement/instantiate my own Runnable and include custom variable/logic to interrupt this myself?
